# Jasper Book Table of content navigation in Docx export

Tags: jasper-reports

I am generating a jasper book with Table of contents and need to export it as DOCx. The problem is when I click on the first level bookmark in TOC, nothing happens. And when I click any second level label in TOC Jasper jumps up to the cover page (**in PDF export clicking the second level label jumps to the right anchor in the report**). I have anchor levels 1 and 2 and link target is self with type none.
**TOC JRXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TocReport">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter"     value="dbOne"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="cm"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="false"/>
<template><![CDATA[$P{resourcePath}+"Berichtsformatvorlagen.jrtx"]]>   </template>
<parameter name="resourcePath" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="Stand" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<parameter name="ErfassungsJahr" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="level" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="label" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="pageIndex" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<variable name="level2Index" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{level} == 1 ? 0 : ($F{level} == 2 ? ($V{level2Index} + 1) : $V{level2Index})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="50">
        <textField>
            <reportElement style="Formatvorlage Standard (kleiner) + 9 Pt." x="0" y="0" width="133" height="30" uuid="d0084fee-c683-41f4-b554-e86d94ed78e5"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["QA Indicator"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="50">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="469" height="49" forecolor="#000000" uuid="24731f07-d115-4be4-a22c-aa9a4c3fc786">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineColor="#A0D042"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font size="35" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Inhaltsverzeichnis"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="10" y="0" width="389" height="20" uuid="b19a02f7-3d3f-4086-86ed-5dc6859e5fd1"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="399" y="0" width="70" height="20" uuid="bc43bd36-7466-457c-95e6-384410c05cbe"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + ($F{pageIndex}+2 )]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
    <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{level}==2]]></printWhenExpression>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="21" y="5" width="376" height="20" uuid="379fcff2-021d-4761-a89a-eeb772723b1b">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="398" y="4" width="71" height="21" uuid="207a4316-1f91-4886-91f9-9a86c788a83f"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{PAGE_NUMBER} + $F{pageIndex} + 2)]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField evaluationTime="Master">
            <reportElement style="Fußzeile " isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="389" y="2" width="80" height="12" uuid="f9665296-c4e6-4f16-9b33-50619eac6150">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="cm"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font size="7"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE} != null ? $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE} : $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement style="Fußzeile " x="0" y="1" width="140" height="14" uuid="df8b430d-9e08-4c4d-9735-58c22a2332aa"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["© Inst "+$P{Year}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement style="Fußzeile " x="184" y="1" width="100" height="12" uuid="1dccae39-e129-4892-81cb-0a36e493b0ca"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" Stand: " + $P{Stand}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

First Level anchor part snippet:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" bookmarkLevel="1">
            <reportElement style="Überschrift 1" x="10" y="0" width="448" height="20" uuid="9c245808-6844-4ba6-a5b2-23e476834efb"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Ueberschrift}]]></textFieldExpression>
            <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$F{Ueberschrift}]]></anchorNameExpression>
        </textField>
```

Second level example:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" bookmarkLevel="2">
                <reportElement style="Überschrift 2" x="0" y="0" width="469" height="20" uuid="d6fbfb76-a764-4752-a996-95c1589a1ad5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Ueberschrift}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA[$F{Ueberschrift}]]></anchorNameExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{Qiid}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
```

Comment: Do you think you can put together a [mcve]?, it would be easier for us to test and try to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that the text to be shown in TOC was too long for Jasper (longer than 40 chars). For your TOC label set the Bookmark level to zero and set hyperlink anchor expression to

```
 $F{title}.length()>40?$F{title}.substring(0,39):$F{title}
```

Text field looks like:

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor">
                <reportElement key="" style="Standard 10pt." x="0" y="0" width="410" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b19a02f7-3d3f-4086-86ed-5dc6859e5fd1"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}.length()>40?$F{label}.substring(0,39):$F{label}]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
```

and you need to create a text field without any text and with level 0 beside your text field with your real text and set anchor name expression to

```
$F{title}.length()>40?$F{title}.substring(0,39):$F{title}
```

Now it works for Docx export